# Как очистить с карты все текущие метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу найти решения:

Есть карта с кластеризацией, массив координат и массив данных к этим координатам.

Я вывожу сперва на карту весь массив координат в виде меток.

Далее пользователь может применить несколько фильтров из массива данных, я хочу очищать карту и наносить новые метки, которые соответствуют фильтрам.

Всего меток 162, после фильтра остается 7, перед применением фильтра и нанесением новых меток выполняю **myMap.geoObjects.removeAll()**
Все метки с карты пропадают, добавляю 7 полученных меток, но карта отрисовывает мне 169 меток (все старые+7 новых). Каждое выполнение  функции с фильтром просто прибавляет одинаковых меток в одни и те-же точки, будто removeAll() просто скрывает старые.

Подскажите, как очистить все метки с текущей карты?

функция добавления меток:

```css
function lod(target_array_adress,target_array_coords){
       for(var i = 0, len = target_array_coords.length; i < len; i++){
        geoObjects[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(target_array_coords[i],  
        getPointData(i,target_array_adress,target_array_coords)/*,
        getPointOptions()*/);
       }
     clusterer.options.set({
        gridSize: 80,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });

    clusterer.add(geoObjects);
    myMap.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

    myMap.setBounds(clusterer.getBounds(), {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myMap.geoObjects.removeAll()` очищает коллекцию геообъектов карты.

У Clusterer тоже есть метод `removeAll()`, он удаляет все геообъекты из кластеризатора:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Clusterer-docpage/#method_detail__removeAll

Comment: Спасибо! 
Еще дополнительно пришлось очищать массив geoObjects, все работает =)